Request from React app to Flask server failing to include cookies
I'm trying to send a get request with cookies from my React app to Flask server. Both are locally hosted with different origin.
Request from react:
export async function fetchUser() {
    try {
        const res = await fetch(`${BASE_URL}/user`, {
            method: 'GET',
            credentials: 'include', 
        });
        if (res.ok) {
            const data = await res.json();
            return data.user; // or wtv format it is
        } else {
            const data = await res.json();
            console.log(data)
            return null
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        return null
    }


Flask app:
app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app, supports_credentials=True, resources={r"/*": {"origins": ['http://localhost:5173']}})

def token_required(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def decorated(*args, **kwargs):
        token = request.cookies.get('token', 0)  # Get the token from cookies
        print(token)
        if token is 0:
            return jsonify({'message': 'Token is missing!'}), 401
        result = enc.validate_token(token)
        if not result['success']:
            return jsonify({'message': result['message']}), 401
        identity = result['identity']
        return f(identity, *args, **kwargs)
    return decorated

@app.route("/user", methods=['GET'])
@token_required
def get_user(current_user):
    if not current_user:
        return jsonify({'error': 'User not found!'}), 404
    return current_user

@app.route("/login", methods=['POST'])
def login():
    data = request.get_json()
    username = data['username']
    password = data['password']
    login = au.handle_login(username, password)
    if login['success']:
        response = make_response(jsonify({ 'success': login['success'], 'message': login['message'] }), 200)
        response.set_cookie(
            "token",
            value=login['token'],
            expires=login['expires'],
            max_age=login['max_age'],
            httponly=True,    # Prevent JavaScript access
            secure=False,      # TRUE: Only over HTTPS in production
            samesite="Lax" # STRICT: Protect against CSRF
        )
        return response, 200
    return jsonify(login), 401


The cookie is set from the same flask server through a different route, and the application cookies tab shows that it's there with the correct key token. I've added credentials: 'include' in the request and supports_credentials=True in the flask CORS config, but in the /user route, request.cookies.get('token') is returning None.
Nothing seems out of place and I've ran out of ideas to try - if anyone can help figure out what's up I'd be so grateful

have you tried disabling CORS? is it required?

disabling cors doesn't work without proxying but this is to be used in a production server as well
